# how can I ignore a variable string length between two known strings when splitting in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I'm brand new to JavaScript an quite a novice to coding in general, but I'm trying to self teach myself as much as possible.

I am trying to extract data from a variable string. The original string is in the following format:

```
CAMERA NAME(NUM):   North West Rd(D1) 
CAMERA NAME(NUM):   Even Longer Camera Name(D2) 
CAMERA NAME(NUM):   Cam13(D13)
```

All I want is the string within the final brackets. I was hoping to have a split function which I could say something along the lines of

```
str.split(CAMERA NAME(NUM):    **variable Characters and length** (,);
```

But I'm unsure how to account for the variable text and length in between (NUM): and (

I'd be very grateful for any suggestion, Thanks!

P.s - I'm currently using this method which works, but I'd like to know how to account for variable strings for future projects, as this will almost certainly come up again.

Thank you.
Luke

```
var txt = msg.payload;
var array = [];
var newTxt = txt.split('(');
//node.warn(newTxt);
for (var i = 1; i < newTxt.length; i++) {
   array.push(newTxt[i].split(')')[0]);
}
//node.warn(array[1]);
msg.payload = array[1];
return msg;
```

Comment: Use a regex, Luke.

Comment: e.g. `^.+\((.+)\)$`

Answer (score 2):

If your outcome is allways like your provided example you can do this with one liner:

```js
let val = "CAMERA NAME(NUM):   North West Rd(D1)"
let res = val.split("(").pop().replace(")", "")
console.log(res)
```

```js
let val = ["CAMERA NAME(NUM):   North West Rd(D1)",
  "CAMERA NAME(NUM):   Even Longer Camera Name(D2)",
  "CAMERA NAME(NUM):   Cam13(D13)"
]

val.forEach(i => {
  let res = i.split("(").pop().replace(")", "")
  console.log(res)
})
```

Split the string at `(`, take just last of array using `pop()`, and remove `)`

Answer (score 1):

Use regex:

```js
const aCamera = [
  "CAMERA NAME(NUM):   North West Rd(D1)",
  "CAMERA NAME(NUM):   Even Longer Camera Name(D2)",
  "CAMERA NAME(NUM):   Cam13(D13)"
];
const oRegex = /\(([A-Za-z0-9]+)\)$/;

aCamera.forEach(sCamName => {
   let aResult = sCamName.match(oRegex);
   if(aResult && aResult [1]){ //Check if there's a result
    console.log(aResult [1]);
   }       
});
```

Comment: The most simple and efficient in my opinion.

Comment: Change `*` to `+` and make sure that you got a match before doing `[1]`, because doing [1] on null will throw an error.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte it also requires a limit set of characters within the braces, when no such criteria was mentioned by the OP.

Comment: @some: It can be solved using: `aArray.reduce((c,s) => { m=s.match(regex); return m ? [...c,m[1]] : c }, []);`

Comment: @Alnitak: it isn't really a problem, it's easy to change a character class to whatever you want. The most important thing here is that the pattern starts directly with the literal parenthesis, and this without to try to check the begining of the string.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte sure, it can be changed, but in general an answer should never introduce constraints or make assumptions about the input data that aren't explicitly called out by the OP.

Comment: @Alnitak: Certainly, but it must be admitted that this is wishful thinking, yourself in your answer you suppose that in case of failure of the pattern, the original string must be returned, and most of the answers suppose that there's no trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex:

```
const val = 'CAMERA NAME(NUM):   Even Longer Camera Name(D2)';
const id = val.replace(/^.+\((.+)\)$/, '$1');
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mention there are 2 parts, you can match both of them making sure that they are there while capturing the last part in a group.

```
\([^()]+\):.*\(([^()]+)\)$
```

- `\([^()]+\):` Match the part with the parenthesis ending with `:`
- `.*` Optionally match any char (The variable part)
- `\(([^()]+)\)` Match `(`, capture in **group 1** any char except parenthesis, and match `)`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e6xst2/1)

```js
const regex = /\([^()]+\):.*\(([^()]+)\)$/gm;
const s = `CAMERA NAME(NUM):   North West Rd(D1)
CAMERA NAME(NUM):   Even Longer Camera Name(D2)
CAMERA NAME(NUM):   Cam13(D13)`;
console.log(Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this using regex.
You can do experiments with Regex using https://regexr.com/5uaag

```js
// move all relevant information to groups
var regex = /([^\n()]+)\(([^()]+)\):\s*([^()]+)\(([^()]+)\)/g;

// ([^\n()]+): move all Chars that are not newlines or brakes in a group
//  \(([^()]+)\): move all chars wrapped in brakes to a group

var test = `CAMERA NAME(NUM):   North West Rd(D1)
CAMERA NAME(NUM):   Even Longer Camera Name(D2)
CAMERA NAME(NUM):   Cam13(D13)`;

var cameras = [];
var match = regex.exec(test);

while(match) {
  // attributes can be changes as you wish
  cameras.push({
    name: match[1],
    num: match[2],
    location: match[3],
    locationTag: match[4]
  });
  match = regex.exec(test);
}

console.log(cameras);
// now you can iterate the cameras array and read the information easily
```